# Work-light: Issue with setting up the environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console

I have started learning IBM worklight recently.I have set the environment.

Now, I am trying to test a simple helloWorklight demo app but i am not able to do deploy and build the app.Although i am following this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

The error what i am getting is.. when trying to run on worklight development server:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.6.0_01-b06 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application _MobileBrowserSimulator. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 25
\\E\[\^/\]\+\\Q\\E\[\^/\]\+\\Q
                         ^
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://duczsl29.zylog-blr.com:10080/FirstDemoApp/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/worklight/server/bundle/api/WorklightBundles
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.internalFindClass(AppClassLoader.java:214)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0279E: Error occured while processing global listeners for the application {0}: {1}
java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [authenticationFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application FirstDemoApp started in 1.958 seconds.[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:557)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:78)
    ... 1 more


[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:557)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:78)
    ... 1 more
```

Also my worklight console is not opening, error is:

```
Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: Internal Server Error; Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [authenticationFilter]: 
Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.class
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? I think I saw this before and it was actually about malformed (invalid) HTML.

Comment: com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter is part of worklight-jee-library-xxxxxx.jar (where xxxxxx is the version number). If you are using the internal server of Worklight Studio, you will find that file in <yourworkspace>/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources. For an external server, the file is at a corresponding location, depending on your installation. Can you verify that the file is there and that server.xml (in the internal server <yourworkspace>/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/server.xml) refers to it?

Comment: @IdanAdar: I didn't change anything in html as this is my first demo app.I followed this pdf: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_01_Creating_your_first_Hybrid_Worklight_application.pdf

Comment: Try with a new eclipse installation (make sure you're using Eclipse Java EE Kepler or Luna), new workspace, new plug-in installation the eclipse marketplace.

Comment: @GeorgSander: I checked worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar, it is there as the path you mentioned and server.xml also pointing the same ..  <library id="worklight-6.1.0">
        <fileset dir="F:\Vishakha_WorklightSpace\WorklightServerConfig\shared\resources" includes="worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar"/>
    </library>

Comment: Make sure you are using either Java 6 or 7; do not use Java 8.

Comment: @IdanAdar First, i followed this link for installation:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/
so used eclipse luna and worklight version 6.1.and got error which i have posted here. Just now I installed fresh eclipse Kepler and worklight version 6.2. Again when i tried to deploy demo app on server i am getting too many errors which i cant post here due to limited characters. so just mentioning error numbers-SRVE0280E,SRVE0293E,SRVE0279E,SRVE0276E,SRVE0321E,SRVE0315E.

Comment: @IdanAdar using java 7

Comment: I don't know. Something in your setup is majorly screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Verify server.xml file of Worklight Development Server.

Check all `<library>` tags make sure they are pointing to correct path.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Wise advise on validating all  tags. To begin with, where is 'shared.resource.dir' declared? Wherever it is, the path to it supposedly is '/usr/shared/resources', where we can crawl into the subdirectories and find the corresponding libraries. I found out that a db2 library contained in db2 directory right below resources does work, whereas that in db2 directory below worklight subdirectory, albeit more recent, does not work. Therefore, I copied and replaced the ailing one with the good one... :-) and, well, at least the error message became different. :-D